# Force all new links to same domain to reuse single browser tab

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs

I want Firefox to use the same tab for all URLs in a single domain. In other words, if I already have [Bugzilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bugzilla) open in one tab, and I click a new Bugzilla link from an email, the new link will open in that existing tab (or in a new tab while closing the old tab).

Is there a way to do this?

[Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_4)'s [application tabs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox_4#Features) seemed so promising. If I create an application tab for Bugzilla, new links to Bugzilla will open in that tab right? Wrong. They still open in a new tab.

I tried the "Close other tabs" add-on for Firefox, which has an option for "Close tabs with this domain". That's *almost* it, but no, it closes ALL tabs with the current domain. And I don't want to close them all, I want to close the old ones.

Basically, like a desktop application, I want ONE instance of each web application running at all times. It seems like such an obvious desire, especially for those that work on software, that I'm surprised I can't find anybody saying anything about it anywhere.

Is it possible?

Comment: I have to disagree with your premise. Using your bugzilla example, being prevented from viewing two tickets at once (say, to compare and see if they're duplicates) does not strike me as being useful in any way whatsoever. Nor does losing track of the ticket I was working on just because I clicked an emailed link to a different ticket. I find being able to concurrently use multiple views of the same application's data to be far more useful than the behavior you describe.

Answer (score 2):

I created a Firefox extension for this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/reuse-tab/

If you pin a tab with Bugzilla, further links to Bugzilla are opened in the pinned tab instead of new tabs.

Comment: This helps! I would prefer not to have to pin the tab though :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm not saying there *can't* exist the kind of solution you are after but it's somewhat against the way the browsers and the web itself current work.

It sounds as an interesting idea and it could be worth adding a feature request for open source browser communities.

Comment: I think its possible, when wordpress does its preview in new tab it keeps using it instead of creating new.

Comment: Yes, sure it's possible *for a web page/app* - it has complete control over the links it opens and can open all links to a single named tab. However, I'm not familiar with a way to instruct a browser to open *all* actions to a domain to reuse the same tab. The example in the question specified that the link was opened from an email.